# Get Compiz working on x1300 ati

Tags: 10.10, compiz, ati

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on a thinkpad T60 with an ati mobile x1300.  Ubuntu isn't loading any proprietary drivers and compiz doesn't work.  A google search turned up nothing.  Sure, some people reported "bad performance", but I'm not getting any "performance" with compiz and these post were all for previous editions.  I'm new to messing with ati drivers.  Is there a way to make sure xorg-video-ati is loaded?  Do I have to add any voodoo lines somewhere in /etc/X11/? Did anyone else have this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an ATI X1400 and I found that as long as I **don't** install any ATI specific binary drivers (fglrx), then I'm good to go. Also, you'll notice the "ATI binary X.Org driver" description says it's for "newer ATI graphics cards" and apparently that doesn't include us. :)

The good news is, all you have to do is go to the Appearance Preferences control panel and choose Normal, Extra, or Custom under the Visual Effects tab and Ubuntu will load up an appropriate open source x.org driver that will work very nicely.

A handy page to bookmark is [Ubuntu Community Documentation for the Radeon Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

Comment: @wdkrnls, if this answered the question for you, don't forget to mark it as "answered".